# Accessing data in my json from api is partially working with react

Tags: reactjs

why does my first dropdown work and the second one not :

```
export default function Actors() {
    const [actors, setActors] = useState()
    const [selActors, setSelActors] = useState()
    const [selMembers, setSelMembers] = useState()
  
    ...
return (
    <Dropdown
        label={selActors?. title?? ''}
        items={actors}
        onSelect={({ value }) => setSelActors(actors.(i => i.id === value))}
    />
    <Dropdown
    label={selMembers?. Members[0]?.name?? ''}
    items={actors}
    onSelect={({ value }) => setSelMembers(actors.Members[0].(i => i.id === value))}
    />
)}
```

My json:

```
{
    "actors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title1",
            "description": "Yadayadayada",
            "Members": [
                {
                    "member_id": 1,
                    "name": "Whoami",
                    "life": [
                        {
                            "age": 13,
                            "sex": "Male"
                        },
              ...
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess I should use map maybe ? I think the way I'm accessing the data in the second piece of code is not the right way to do...

Comment: this `name: i.Members.name` shouldn't be `name: i.Members[0].name`?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, I've edited the issue

Comment: It seems like you call the same API twice (you should clarify this)? Why not just process the `Members` from your `actors`?

Comment: @crashmstr I've edited the issue, it was not clear

Comment: There is no `actors.Members[0]`, `actors` in an array.

Comment: should I try `Members[0]` directly ?

Comment: \* (`actors` is an array)

Comment: But how do I access the `member_id` ?

Comment: ... I'm not sure what the confusion is. `actors` is an array. The first member is at `actors[0].Members[0]`. Whether or not if these things being in arrays actually matters we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Well, in my second Dropdown I wan to access to `member_id` in my label and it's not woking

Comment: Yes, because `actors` is an array, but you attempt to access `actors.Members[0]`. Arrays do not have a `Members` property by default. The first member is at `actors[0].Members[0]`. Whether or not it matters that `actors` in an array depends on your specific application.